# array over write and for each error

Tags: php, email

i want to get each grab emails body in to separately array[like as email1-->array1  & email2-->array2  ]  and write in to mysql ,but it seems continuous[my inbox has 2 emails]..help me

```
<HTML>
   <HEAD>    
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </HEAD>
<?php
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'mail@gmail.com';
$password = 'pass';

$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');
if($emails) {
    rsort($emails);
    foreach($emails as $email_number) {
    $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);

 include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = str_get_html("$message"); 
foreach($html->find('tr') as $e) {
    $b = $e->find('td',1)->plaintext;
$EMailArr[] =$b ;
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($EMailArr);
echo '</pre>';

$connection=mysql_connect (localhost,slt,slt);
if (!$connection) {
  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(dbtest, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}
$value_string3 = "'".implode("','", $EMailArr)."'";
mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (`a`,`b`,`c`,`d`,`e`,`f`,`g`,`h`,`i`) VALUES($value_string3)");
print "INSERT INTO test (`a`,`b`,`c`,`d`,`e`,`f`,`g`,`h`,`i`) VALUES($value_string3)";
mysql_close($connection);
    }
} 
imap_close($inbox);
?>
</HTML>
```

out puts..

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] =>   MD-MAL_MSAG5200_01 - MD-Malwana - ZTE  
    [2] =>   8/23/2013 4:33:51 AM  
    [3] =>   CRITICAL   
    [4] =>   MD-MAL_MSAG5200_01 - MD-Malwana - ZTE Isolated   
    [5] =>   All customers(49) in above MD-MAL_MSAG5200_01 DSLAM/=  MSAN  
    [6] =>   PENDING  
    [7] =>   FMT-BB(A)  
    [8] =>   OPEN  
    [9] =>   PENDING  
    [10] =>   Informed to DGM : idsmanjuka@gmail.com  
    [11] => =  
)
INSERT INTO test (`a`,`b`,`c`,`d`,`e`,`f`,`g`,`h`,`i`) VALUES('',' MD-MAL_MSAG5200_01 - MD-Malwana - ZTE ',' 8/23/2013 4:33:51 AM ',' CRITICAL ',' MD-MAL_MSAG5200_01 - MD-Malwana - ZTE Isolated ',' All customers(49) in above MD-MAL_MSAG5200_01 DSLAM/= MSAN ',' PENDING ',' FMT-BB(A) ',' OPEN ',' PENDING ',' Informed to DGM : idsmanjuka@gmail.com ','= ')
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] =>   MD-MAL_MSAG5200_01 - MD-Malwana - ZTE  
    [2] =>   8/23/2013 4:33:51 AM  
    [3] =>   CRITICAL   
    [4] =>   MD-MAL_MSAG5200_01 - MD-Malwana - ZTE Isolated   
    [5] =>   All customers(49) in above MD-MAL_MSAG5200_01 DSLAM/=  MSAN  
    [6] =>   PENDING  
    [7] =>   FMT-BB(A)  
    [8] =>   OPEN  
    [9] =>   PENDING  
    [10] =>   Informed to DGM : idsmanjuka@gmail.com  
    [11] => =  
    [12] => MD-MAL_MSAG5200_01 - MD-Malwana - ZTE
    [13] =>   CRITICAL
    [14] => MD-MAL_MSAG5200_01 - MD-Malwana - ZTE Isolated
    [15] => All customers(49) in above MD-MAL_MSAG5200_01 DSLAM/=3D MSAN  
    [16] => PENDING
    [17] => =  FMT-BB(A)
    [18] =>   OPEN
    [19] => PENDING
    [20] => Informed to DGM :idsmanjuka@gmail.com  
)
INSERT INTO test (`a`,`b`,`c`,`d`,`e`,`f`,`g`,`h`,`i`) VALUES('',' MD-MAL_MSAG5200_01 - MD-Malwana - ZTE ',' 8/23/2013 4:33:51 AM ',' CRITICAL ',' MD-MAL_MSAG5200_01 - MD-Malwana - ZTE Isolated ',' All customers(49) in above MD-MAL_MSAG5200_01 DSLAM/= MSAN ',' PENDING ',' FMT-BB(A) ',' OPEN ',' PENDING ',' Informed to DGM : idsmanjuka@gmail.com ','= ','MD-MAL_MSAG5200_01 - MD-Malwana - ZTE',' CRITICAL','MD-MAL_MSAG5200_01 - MD-Malwana - ZTE Isolated','All customers(49) in above MD-MAL_MSAG5200_01 DSLAM/=3D MSAN ','PENDING','= FMT-BB(A)',' OPEN','PENDING','Informed to DGM :idsmanjuka@gmail.com ')
```

i seems its over write issue.but i dont knw hw to correct it..
ur help is highly appreciated...

Comment: why my 2nd array comes with first array repeatly

Comment: any one can help me to find what's wrong with my looping

Comment: it seems that you haven't close any loop and condition. add full code with proper closing statement

Comment: Awlad Liton  ..my full code submitted.